# Having trouble to find correct way to generate output

Tags: python

I ran into some trouble in my coding practice session, its a classic car service practice.
The output should include: full menu, let user choose 2 service, and a car shop invoice which should given 2 car service customer choose and the total price

```
def main():
    print("Zooey's (College Fund) Car Shop Services, \nOil change -- $35 \nTire rotation -- $19 \nCar wash -- $7 \nCar wax -- $1 ")

    select_svc1 = input("select first service : ")
    select_svc2 = input("select second service : ")

    if(select_svc1=="-"):
        select_svc1="No service"

    else:
        select_svc1=select_svc1.lower()
    if(select_svc1 == "Oil change"):
        select_svc1=select_svc1+", $35"

    elif(select_svc1 == "Tire rotation"):
        select_svc1=select_svc1+", $19"

    elif(select_svc1 == "Car wash"):
        select_svc1=select_svc1+", $7"

    elif(select_svc1 == "Car wax"):
        select_svc1=select_svc1+", $12"

    if(select_svc2=="-"):
        select_svc2="No service"

    else:
        select_svc2=select_svc2.lower()
    if(select_svc2 == "Oil change"):
        select_svc2=select_svc2+", $35"

    elif(select_svc2 == "Tire rotation"):
        select_svc2=select_svc2+", $19"

    elif(select_svc2 == "Car wash"):
        select_svc2=select_svc2+", $7"

    elif(select_svc2 == "Car wax"):
        select_svc2=select_svc2+", $12"

    print ("\Zooey's (College Fund) Car Shop Services invoice")
    print("first service : "+select_svc1)
    print("second service : "+select_svc2)
```

Comment: And? what's the problem?

Comment: What is the error or issue?

Comment: It does not generate any output for how ever I adjust the code

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: The output I am expecting are: full menu, let user choose 2 service, and a car shop invoice which should given 2 car service customer choose and the total price

Comment: Add main() outside of the function. Call the script from terminal like  python <name>.py

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1:**

add:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In short, when you run python module, the [`__name__`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/) built in variable gets the value of `'__main__'`. if the module is imported, `__name__` gets the imported module's name.

**Alternative 2:**

add a function call to `main()` in the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `select_svc1=select_svc1.lower()` and then compare that with string that has upper character so of course it will not do anything. To fix this, just remove all the `lower()` calls.

```
print("Zooey's (College Fund) Car Shop Services, \nOil change -- $35 \nTire rotation -- $19 \nCar wash -- $7 \nCar wax -- $1 ")

select_svc1 = input("select first service : ")
select_svc2 = input("select second service : ")

if(select_svc1=="-"):
    select_svc1="No service"

if(select_svc1 == "Oil change"):
    select_svc1=select_svc1+", $35"

elif(select_svc1 == "Tire rotation"):
    select_svc1=select_svc1+", $19"

elif(select_svc1 == "Car wash"):
    select_svc1=select_svc1+", $7"

elif(select_svc1 == "Car wax"):
    select_svc1=select_svc1+", $12"

if(select_svc2=="-"):
    select_svc2="No service"

if(select_svc2 == "Oil change"):
    select_svc2=select_svc2+", $35"

elif(select_svc2 == "Tire rotation"):
    select_svc2=select_svc2+", $19"

elif(select_svc2 == "Car wash"):
    select_svc2=select_svc2+", $7"

elif(select_svc2 == "Car wax"):
    select_svc2=select_svc2+", $12"

print ("\Zooey's (College Fund) Car Shop Services invoice")
print("first service : "+select_svc1)
print("second service : "+select_svc2)
```

Output:

```
Zooey's (College Fund) Car Shop Services, 
Oil change -- $35 
Tire rotation -- $19 
Car wash -- $7 
Car wax -- $1 
select first service : Oil change
select second service : Car wash
\Zooey's (College Fund) Car Shop Services invoice
first service : Oil change, $35
second service : Car wash, $7
```